# How to reduce the space vertically and horizontally between sub figures in Latex?

Tags: graphics

I have 6 graphs and in I put 2 graphs in a row (Parallel) it means used 3 rows for 6 graphs. Now It having more spaces vertically (can see in image **in RED**) and horizontal (can see in the image **in Blue**).

Please help me, how can I reduce the size between subfigures horizontally and vertically?

```
\begin{figure}[ht]
\centring 
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
\centring 
\includegraphics[scale=0.45]{RHKNN.eps}
\caption{}
\label{fig:a1}
\end{subfigure}
\hfill
\centring 
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
\centring 
\includegraphics[scale=0.45]{LHKNN.eps}
\caption{}
\label{fig:b1}
\end{subfigure}
\newline
%\par\midskip % force a bit of vertical whitespace
%\centring 
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
  \centring 
     \includegraphics[scale=0.45]{TPKNN.eps}
     \caption{}
     \label{fig:c1}
\end{subfigure}
\hfill
\centring 
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
  \centring 
     \includegraphics[scale=0.45]{RHDT.eps}
     \caption{}
     \label{fig:d1}
\end{subfigure}\\
%\par\midskip % force a bit of vertical whitespace
\centring 
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
  \centring 
     \includegraphics[scale=0.45]{LHDT.eps}
     \caption{}
     \label{fig:e1}
\end{subfigure}
\hfill
\centring 
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
  \centring 
     \includegraphics[scale=0.45]{TPDT.eps}
     \caption{}
     \label{fig:f1}
\end{subfigure}
\hfill
\caption{The impact of long ABC; ~\ref{fig:a1} a by using K; ~\ref{fig:b1} H position  by using K; ~\ref{fig:c1} f by using K; ~\ref{fig:d1} z by using D; ~\ref{fig:e1} a by using D; ~\ref{fig:f1} T position by using D}
\label{fig 4:gr2}
\end{figure}
```

[image] [image]

Comment: Hi there! Does this code you have provided honestly work for you? Shouldn't `\centring` be `\centering`

Comment: your problem are your pictures. apparently they have white space around them. to see this put `\includegraphics[scale=0.45]{RHDT.eps}` (and all other pictures) in `\frame{...}`.. if i'm right, than you need to trim this white space.

Comment: @Au101 I edited with \centering, still same problem.

Comment: How can I trim the white spaces @Zarko

Comment: i don't know, how images are generated. manysoftweres for generating such images has option to define border around image. you can also use some programs (like snipping tool in windows) which is capable to trim image showed on screen.

Comment: I export image from Matlab to Latex in eps form

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem. Especially you can use `\includegraphics{example-image}`, because we don't have your image files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After struggling 10 to 12 hours I reached some solution, I removed `\hfill` from the code and used `\begin{figure*}[t!]` instead of `\begin{figure}[ht]`.

Here is the code:

```
\begin{figure*}[t!]
\centring 
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
\centring 
\includegraphics[scale=0.45]{RHKNN.eps}
\caption{}
\label{fig:a1}
\end{subfigure}
\centring 
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
\centring 
\includegraphics[scale=0.45]{LHKNN.eps}
\caption{}
\label{fig:b1}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
  \centring 
     \includegraphics[scale=0.45]{TPKNN.eps}
     \caption{}
     \label{fig:c1}
\end{subfigure}
\centring 
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
  \centring 
     \includegraphics[scale=0.45]{RHDT.eps}
     \caption{}
     \label{fig:d1}
\end{subfigure}\\
\centring 
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
  \centring 
     \includegraphics[scale=0.45]{LHDT.eps}
     \caption{}
     \label{fig:e1}
\end{subfigure}
\centring 
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
  \centring 
     \includegraphics[scale=0.45]{TPDT.eps}
     \caption{}
     \label{fig:f1}
\end{subfigure}

\caption[A set of six sub figures.]{The impact of ABC:
\textbf{(\subref{fig:a1})} app by using K;
\textbf{(\subref{fig:b1})} La  by using Ka;
\textbf{(\subref{fig:c1})} Ta  by using K;
\textbf{(\subref{fig:d1})} Ra by using Da; 
\textbf{(\subref{fig:e1})} Aa by using Db;
\textbf{(\subref{fig:f1})} To by using Da
}%
\label{fig 4:gr2}
\end{figure*}
```